# Condition exist array id with id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have query :

```
Product.all.where(x: @id)
```

With

```
x = ["9", "8", "7","5"] # Array exam

# And 

@id = 5
```

How to check if `5` is in `array`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  How does product relate to the array?

Comment: Common query : Product.all.where(id: xxxx) with : xxxx is array . but in this case opposite query xxxx change to id and id change to xxxx

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean, there isn't an "opposite" query.  If you have the id you can just do `Product.find(@id)`

Comment: Product.find(@id) for only id . in this case Product.find_by_catalogs or Product.where(x: @idx)

Answer (score 0):

x = [9, 8, 7, 5] # Array exam

@id = 5

```
if x.include?(@id)
 Product.find(@id)
end
```

or

`Product.find(@id) if x.include?(@id)`